# How to remove lamba library in android?

Tags: android, retrolambda

I have started coding on a pre written code by some other developer  and it has : 'me.tatarka.retrolambda' , what is its impact on the size of the apk.

These are the lines in gradle file;

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

retrolambda {
jvmArgs '-noverify'
}
```

Comment: Do you need lambda support in your code?

Comment: I don't know what it is doing in the app if it has a large size then i surely dont want to use it.

Comment: If you don't need it delete it and sync your app. If you get errors try to resolve them.

Comment: tried doing that but it has some impact on the gradle generating apk as if i remove it i am not able to process my apk should i post the error

Comment: An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_60). Please file a bug at the Java Bug Database (http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/) after checking the database for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for java.lang.invoke.MethodType not found
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 6.339 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings

Comment: https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda#proguard

Comment: please elaborate i am not able to extract how can i remove retrolamda by that page

Comment: Try to delete everything that is related to retrolambda.

Comment: Please let me know why my question has been given a negative reputation and who did it no offense just like to know what was wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to create a new project and applied the plugin retro lambda it has no effect on the apk size so i don't think it has ant impact on  my app it is a backward compatible library This plugin will automatically build your java or android project with retrolambda, giving you lambda goodness on java 6 or 7.  for more information pls refer to :
github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda#proguard